# How to test child components from a PrefetchResourceContainer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing my company code with Enzyme and Jest and have come across an issue with some of our class components.

I have attempted a few ways of shallow and mount rendering but to no avail. The closest I have gotten to what I need is this code.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<LoanFilesContainer store={store}/>)
  })

  it('LoanFilesContainer snapshot shallow renderer test', () => {
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })


  it('LoanFilesContainer snapshot test', () => {
    const prefetch_wrapper = mount(component.get(0))
    console.log(prefetch_wrapper.childAt(0).debug())
  })
```

Above you can see my test for the prefetch_wrapper. I have been printing it to the console and I receive some good information but not exactly what I need. That log statement returns:

```
<PrefetchResourceContainer store={{...}} loan_csv_mapping={{...}} default_allocation_mode="automatically" is_using_amc={false} actions={{...}} storeSubscription={{...}} loans={{...}}>
  <Connect(PrefetchResourceContainer) store={{...}} loan_csv_mapping={{...}} default_allocation_mode="automatically" is_using_amc={false} actions={{...}} storeSubscription={{...}} loans={{...}}>
    <PrefetchResourceContainer store={{...}} loan_csv_mapping={{...}} default_allocation_mode="automatically" is_using_amc={false} actions={{...}} storeSubscription={{...}} loans={{...}} fees={{...}}> 
      <Connect(Connect(LoanFilesContainer)) store={{...}} loan_csv_mapping={{...}} default_allocation_mode="automatically" is_using_amc={false} actions={{...}} storeSubscription={{...}} loans={{...}} fees={{...}}>
        <Connect(LoanFilesContainer) store={{...}} loan_csv_mapping={{...}} default_allocation_mode="automatically" is_using_amc={false} actions={{...}} storeSubscription={{...}} loans={{...}} fees={{...}} orderAdd={{...}}>
          <LoanFilesContainer store={{...}} loan_csv_mapping={{...}} default_allocation_mode="automatically" is_using_amc={false} actions={{...}} storeSubscription={{...}} loans={{...}} fees={{...}} orderAdd={{...}} upload1003={{...}}> 
            <main className="main"> 
              <Loader>
                <div className="loader-container">
                  <img width={100} src={{...}} /> 
                </div>
              </Loader>
            </main>
          </LoanFilesContainer>
        </Connect(LoanFilesContainer>
      </Connect(Connect(LoanFilesContainer))> 
    </PrefetchResourceContainer> 
  </Connect(PrefetchResourceContainer)>
</PrefetchResourceContainer>
```

I need to get the state from `LoanFilesContainer`. How can I dive deeper into the DOM in order to get access to the LoanFilesContainer state.

I need to bypass the Connect wrappers and get into the `LoanFilesContainer`. How can I do so?

Comment: You can add your own solution as an answer and mark this as answered.

Comment: Thanks @AlexRobertson! First time posting on S.O. I have responded with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You can use the find() function to filter through the Wrapper and grab the element you need. The code that fixed this for me was changing:

```
it('LoanFilesContainer snapshot test', () => {
    const prefetch_wrapper = mount(component.get(0))
    console.log(prefetch_wrapper.childAt(0).debug())
  })
```

to:

```
it('LoanFilesContainer snapshot test', () => {
    const prefetch_wrapper = mount(component.get(0))
    const loanContainerWrapper = prefetch_wrapper.find('LoanFilesContainer')
    const state = loanContainerWrapper.instance().state
  })
```